# How to set up a Terraform project with a different profile?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

For some odd reason, my AWS provider in Terraform is not taking the credentials.

I can confirm it's a full AWS admin account (not secure but for testing purposes) and I have confirmed the bucket exists and in **eu-west-1**, and doesn't have an explicit deny (or any permissions for that matter).

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "4.60.0"
    }
  }

  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "terraform-state-files-test12354567"
    key    = "state/terraform_state.tfstate"
    region = "eu-west-1"
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-1"
  access_key = "the_access_key"
  secret_key = "the_secret"
  #profile  = "tvg" # Just this with region doesn't work either 
}
```

This is the error:

```
Error refreshing state: AccessDenied: Access Denied
    status code: 403, request id: JBCP1JNXZH7TE8JW, host id: ghjkl......
```

I feel like I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Does it work if you specify the access/secret keys in environment variables? (`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`)

Comment: It worked! But that's just making things weirder. Why won't it just take my credentials?

Comment: Which credentials won't it take?

Comment: access_key and secret_key (under provider "aws")

Comment: Because the `provider` block is used to manage the resources in your TF definitions, not for the backend. The fact that the backend happens to also be on AWS is just a coincidence as far as TF is concerned

Comment: You can also use a different profile for the backend by specifying the profile to use in the `backend` block

Comment: Ah! Very easy to miss I guess.
Please put that as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks a ton!